# A lot of div's in one html

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser

I have an experimental problem. I want to make the image with a lot of `div`'s, div's have a `1px` `width` and `height`.
I got a pixel data of image from the `canvas context`, create the div and gave value to each div's `background-color`, it means div's count are equal to image pixels count, but if there is an image for example with 100x56 resolution it's ok, but in case if more than this, browser renders the html very slow.
Part of code below

```
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var data = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {

        var red = data[i];
        var green = data[i + 1];
        var blue = data[i + 2];

        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.style.width = '1px';
        div.style.height = '1px';
        div.style.float='left'
        div.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + red + ',' + green + ',' + blue + ')';
        fragment.appendChild(div);

    }
   cnt.appendChild(fragment)
```

I know this problem is not applicable so much, but I want to know if there is any case to render a lot of elements faster in a browser(I use Chrome) or is it browser-independant?

P.s.: My colleague said "there is no problem in Silverlight like this, you can add even 50000 elements and it will work fine", and I want to give him "my answer"

Thanks

Comment: The experiment is to use only html elements

Comment: Yes it is, but I should draw in canvas, but in this case I make image with div's

Comment: This is a guess, but: I don't see any newlines, so I assume `cnt` is already in the right size. Maybe it's the `float` that's expensive - I'd try moving from float to absolute position, and setting `left` and `top`.

Comment: but I think the problem is not in element style, I think it in count of DIV's and it is hard to render for browser.There is no newlines because cnt have fixed sizes same as image

Comment: You should write your elements in the DOM, not the document.

Comment: Milche Patern: I don't understood what did you mean saying not the document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't append on each loop. Build a string with the output and then do one append. I'd also remove document.createElement and just build it manually.

Another issue is that you're declaring your RGB variables everytime you loop. Declare any variables outside the loop if possible.

Comment: This. DOM operations is very expensive in compare with string concat. Usage of documentFragment should boost up things, but string still will be faster a lot.

Comment: @Tommi exactly. Also, if you need to make changes to the DOM, remove elements, do your changes, then append back as one big chunk.

Comment: But I'am not append on each time, I am create documentFragment and at last it is add to caontainer

Comment: It's still going to be slow as you're using DOM operations. String concatenation is the fastest for large HTML manipulation cause it takes little CPU to place on page. Each time you appendChild, the browser has to work for it. Give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

If the experiment is to use only html elements, I recomend you to get the base 64 image from the canvas and then add it in an img tag.

```
var src = canvas.toDataURL();
var img = document.getElementsById('image_id');
img.src = src;
img.onload = function () {
  console.log('image loaed');
};
```

**If you need the image to be created dynamically**

```
var src = canvas.toDataURL();
var newImg = document.createElement("img");
newImg.src = src;
img.onload = function () {
  document.body.appendChild(newImg);
};
```

Comment: No, experinet is to use a lot of elements to create one image

Comment: Ok, I misunderstand the experiment.